# Android remote server authentication using HttpUrlConnection not sending login/password parameters

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, android-asynctask

I have this code:

```
private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> 
{
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... theParams) 
        {
            String myUrl = theParams[0];
            final String myEmail = theParams[1];
            final String myPassword = theParams[2];


        Log.d( "Inner myURL: " , myUrl );
        Log.d( "myEmail: " , myEmail );
        Log.d( "myPass: " , myPassword );

        Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator()
        {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() 
            {
                return new PasswordAuthentication( myEmail, myPassword.toCharArray());
            }
        });         

        String response = null;

        try 
        {
            final URL url = new URL(myUrl);
            final HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setUseCaches(false);

            final InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            final byte[] buffer = new byte[8196];
            int readCount;
            final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            while ((readCount = is.read(buffer)) > -1) 
            {
                builder.append(new String(buffer, 0, readCount));
            }

            response = builder.toString();      
            Log.d( "After call, response: " , " " + response);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
                Log.d( "Exception: " , "Yup");
                e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;
    }
```

}

But when its executed, the login/password are not sent in the post request to the server. Any idea how I can fix that and have those parameters sent?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        try {
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);

            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", user));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));


            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httppost);

            String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

            System.out.println("Responce is :: " + responseBody);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: this is ok, but it does not use HttpConnection nor does it use DigstAuthentication which is what I am trying to do.